# Asp.net core web api with mongodb 500 error

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I have been following this tutorial [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1267/using-mongodb-nosql-database-with-aspnet-webapi-core). With some help I have finally completed it and attempted to deploy locally on my machine. I get the following error...

[image]

I get no other errors in Visual studios. I am rather new to this so my question is this, How do I diagnose this type of error? I am happy to provide code if necissary, thanks in advance for any help given.

**Git repo**

[Github](https://github.com/bcrawford11/MongoApi)

**Edit**

Photo of IIS express warning...

[image]

Comment: Can you debug and check if your database server is getting connected? Also check if any exception is being thrown

Comment: Yes. In that case check if any exception is being thrown from somewhere.

Comment: Visual studios has nothing, the web console only shows what is in the photo above, and mongod has nothing either. Where else can I look?

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? Can you post the url that you are hitting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127669/discussion-between-pratik-gaikwad-and-bean0341).

Comment: check your IIS, application pool, virtual directory

Comment: Add IIS warning to post

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my issue. In my code I have a postID, What I didn't realize was that MongoDB auto creates an ObjectID referenced as ID. So when it came to calling that object ID I of course used my postID call. This caused the mongo DB to fail, Also I didnt realize the error was being thrown way up at the top of my console window. I have since updated my project in git with the necessary changes.