# How is launchSettings.json referenced in asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, mongodb

I am new to Asp.net core and I have created a web api with mongodb. I am curious as to how my application actually uses launchSettings.json. I have done a solution search and have found no where in my application does it actually reference or call the file.

Is this normal?

and if not where should I be calling it?

I have my project posted [here](https://github.com/bcrawford11/MongoApi) on github

**EDIT**

this question is in response to another one that I have [Asp.net core web api with mongodb 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496214/asp-net-core-web-api-with-mongodb-500-error)