# Can you change the location of launchSettings.json in an ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.NET Core project (created with `dotnet new webapp`), is it possible to change the location of `launchSettings.json`? Currently for it to be recognised I need to have it in a `Properties/` folder, but I would like to rename this to have a lowercase 'p'.

As an extra point; would it also be possible to change the locations of the `appsettings.json` file(s)? Would I be able to put `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json` in another folder, for instance?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513353) is *almost* what I'm looking for, but it was never answered.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `AppDesignerFolder` property in a `PropertyGroup` of your CSPROJ? I'm going solely off of [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a40d411e1eed271772f34e1fa980cc0d00d830f1/Directory.Build.props#L329) and its associated comment, but that might be what you're looking for.

Edit: Ah, nevermind, I see there's more to it as per below.

Comment: I think 'appsettings.json' can be overridden with a bit of work. Behind the scenes, the default HostBuilder is calling `IConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`. You could add your own file provider in Program.cs that looks at a different file or location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that path is hard coded in tools like `dotnet-watch`,

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/v7.0.102/src/BuiltInTools/dotnet-watch/LaunchSettingsProfile.cs#L29

```cs
var launchSettingsPath = Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "Properties", "launchSettings.json");
```

So, you have no flexibility changing it, not even changing the letter casing of `P`.

Comment: Knowing Microsoft, I suspected that would be the case... thanks for the quick answer :>